# Full Screen Activity for App in Android Studio

Tags: android, themes, android-fullscreen

I came across this app (I attach a screen), where you can see that the background of the app also seems to extend into the bar where there is the time, the network status, etc etc, I wanted to try to replicate it but I don't get much
[image]

I tried with this theme

```
<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ice</item>
    </style>
```

But what I get is this:
[image]

Could it be a custom layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by declaring a flag to window in onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
...
}
```

also in app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

You should assign **"android:windowFullscreen"** to **false** to show the status bar.

Hope this fix your issue.